# getting the name of the column in which a value was change (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

is it posible to get the name of the column in which a value was change after an insert or update?, i know that with TG_TABLE_NAME you get the table name in which the value was change, but i want to get the column name is it posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changed columns could be determined by checking the values of the OLD and NEW for each column, for example:

```
IF (OLD.col1 IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.col1) THEN 'col1';
ELSIF (OLD.col2 IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.col2) THEN 'col2';
...
```

I suspect you could do some interesting "except" work on the `OLD` and `NEW` variables, or a `FOR` loop over the NEW variable, so that you don't have hard-code the column list.